# garbage collection in python builtins - sum

Tags: python, garbage-collection

When I try to run the following code in python interpreter, it gives me an obvious MemoryError as I am running an infinite loop in order to check the memory usage.

```
def a():
 i=2
 while True:
  yield i
  i*=i

print sum(a())
```

When I run this code, I can see memory usage of python growing. But, when I get a MemoryError, I can see that the python interpreter process is still holding around 200 MB of memory, even when the sum function is no longer running in the interpreter.
My question is: Are the builtin functions of python not supposed to be very efficient, even in terms of garbage collection? Instead of handling the responsibility of garbage collection to the user, shall the builtin not clear up its own clutter?

Comment: Python's memory management for Integer is a bit more complex than "Memory leaks and garbage collection", you might want to have a look at an explanation here: http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-integer-objects-implementation/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Python Docs on GC on [Free Lists](http://docs.python.org/library/gc.html):

> Not all items in some free lists may be freed due to the particular implementation, in particular int and float.

So allocating a gazillion-infinite integers via a generator will eat all your memory (up to receiving Memory Errors), while not all items may be freed as per the above definition.

But is that memory gone for good? No. The environment keeps it for reuse by your code. The Garbage Collection, being "efficient", does not mean it will reclaim the moment an object leaves scope. It may also mean "let's hang on to that just-used memory, maybe this silly piece of code will want to use it again."

Or as [Effbot](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-doesnt-python-release-the-memory-when-i-delete-a-large-object.htm) tells us:

> Memory that’s returned to a given allocator will be reused by that allocator, even if it’s not returned to the system.

You *can* [force a GC collection](http://docs.python.org/library/gc.html?highlight=gc.collect#gc.collect), but that may actually hinder performance unless you know why and have a very, very good reason to force it.

```
gc.collect([generation])
With no arguments, run a full collection. The optional argument generation may be an integer specifying which generation to collect (from 0 to 2). A ValueError is raised if the generation number is invalid. The number of unreachable objects found is returned.

Changed in version 2.5: The optional generation argument was added.

Changed in version 2.6: The free lists maintained for a number of built-in types are cleared whenever a full collection or collection of the highest generation (2) is run. Not all items in some free lists may be freed due to the particular implementation, in particular int and float.
```

Answer (score 3):

If the python builtins have a memory leak, its a bug.

However, simply because python is still holding onto memory does not mean there is a memory leak. Python has all kinds of fun allocation tricks going on, and so it may be keeping your memory for future usage down the line. So you can't simply look in task manager to see whether or not python is handling the memory properly.

To check for an actual memory leak, one technique is to run your code repeatedly. If its a real memory leak, you should lose memory each time you run it. If its a phantom memory leak, the memory will actually be reused for the second time, and you won't lose any memory.

I ran your code on my Linux box, and while I did found it was using much more memory after running that loop for a while rather then before, running it again didn't use additional memory, in fact some of the memory "lost" in the first run seemed to be recovered.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with the implementation of `sum`, generators, or the garbage collector.

The growing memory usage you're seeing is what is required to hold the value of `i`. Python supports arbitrarily large integers, and each iteration the number of bits required to store `i` doubles. If you change your change your generator function to be:

```
def a():
    i=2
    while True:
        yield i
        i += 1
```

You'll see that the memory footprint is stable.

Comment: I think the OP is interested in why he's not getting the memory back when the sum is terminated, not why it has increasing memory usage.